# Displaying records in a table in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datareader

```
        conn.Open();

        TableRow r = new TableRow();
        TableCell c = new TableCell();

        SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();


          while (reader.Read())
        {
              c.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(reader["Name"].ToString()));
                r.Cells.Add(c);
                Table1.Rows.Add(r);

                c.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(reader["RollID"].ToString()));
                r.Cells.Add(c);
                Table1.Rows.Add(r);
        }
```

I'm using the above code to print data in table.But all fields are coming in a single row(Row not incrementing).Can you tell me how to display in multiple rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, you are creating a single row and cell, and adding all of your controls to that single cell.

While what you want is certainly possible (just make sure you create a new cell for each data element you pull out of your reader, and a new row for each iteration through the while loop), is there a reason you aren't using something like a [`GridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) to present this content?

Comment: Yes,I'm not using GridView because I want to use a dropdown list in the rightnost cell of every row.But I'm getting problems with it.so,tried to use tables instead

Comment: Can u please help me how to print a dropdown list in the table cell here.

Comment: You can utilize a [`TemplateField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.aspx) column in the `GridView` to accomplish this.  There's a fairly good tutorial available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Create a new instance of TableRow for each row. You're just creating 1 instance before iterating through the resultset.

Answer (score 0):

Move your construction of the TableCell and TableRow variables inside of your WHILE loop, at the top.  In this way, you will get a new row and a new cell for each record in the reader.

Consider code that looks like the following (the comments are mine):

```
    conn.Open();

    // MOVE THESE
    /**
    TableRow r = new TableRow();
    TableCell c = new TableCell();
    **/

    SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();


      while (reader.Read())
    {

          // TO HERE..  so that a new row and cell are created for each record in your reader
          TableRow r = new TableRow();
          TableCell c = new TableCell();

          c.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(reader["Name"].ToString()));
            r.Cells.Add(c);
            //Table1.Rows.Add(r);   -- ADD THE ROW AFTER THE SECOND FIELD... THEN YOU HAVE 2 COLUMNS

            c.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(reader["RollID"].ToString()));
            c = new TableCell(); // CREATE A NEW CELL, FOR A NEW COLUMN
            r.Cells.Add(c);
            Table1.Rows.Add(r);
    }
```